# How to underline the whole answer field in xsl-fo?

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

I am trying to make this form in xsl-fo (see the link).

[image]

Unfortunately I have no idea how to make all the underlines. I tried using fo:inline but that only underlines the answer text, not the whole answer field.

Comment: Please show us your code (XML + XSL). thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For empty underlines, use `fo:leader` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_leader) with a bottom border, e.g.:

```
<fo:block>Name:<fo:leader leader-length.optimum="100%" border-bottom="thin solid black"
     /></fo:block>
<fo:block>Address:<fo:leader leader-length.optimum="100%"
        border-bottom="thin solid black" /><fo:block /><fo:leader
        leader-length.optimum="100%" border-bottom="thin solid black" /></fo:block>
```

For long underlines under text, use `fo:inline` with `inline-progression-dimension.optimum` and `inline-progression-dimension.minimum` so the `fo:inline` doesn't have to take 100% of the width:

```
<fo:block>Name:<fo:inline keep-with-previous.within-line="always"
        inline-progression-dimension.minimum="12pt"
        inline-progression-dimension.optimum="100%" border-bottom="thin solid black"
        padding-left="12pt">RECEIVER NAME</fo:inline></fo:block>
<fo:block>Address:<fo:inline keep-with-previous.within-line="always"
        inline-progression-dimension.minimum="12pt"
        inline-progression-dimension.optimum="100%" border-bottom="thin solid black"
        padding-left="12pt">RECEIVER STREET 1</fo:inline><fo:block /><fo:inline
        keep-with-previous.within-line="always"
        inline-progression-dimension.minimum="12pt"
        inline-progression-dimension.optimum="100%" border-bottom="thin solid black"
        padding-left="12pt">2, RECEIVER STREET 3</fo:inline></fo:block>
```

To get the text to line up, if you're using AH Formatter, use `axf:tab` (https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-ext.html#axf.tab) and related properties to set and use tab stops:

```
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" axf:tab-stops="20mm">
    <fo:block>Name:<fo:inline keep-with-previous.within-line="always"
            inline-progression-dimension.minimum="12pt"
            inline-progression-dimension.optimum="100%" border-bottom="thin solid black"
            ><axf:tab />RECEIVER NAME</fo:inline></fo:block>
    <fo:block>Address:<fo:inline keep-with-previous.within-line="always"
            inline-progression-dimension.minimum="12pt"
            inline-progression-dimension.optimum="100%" border-bottom="thin solid black"
            ><axf:tab />RECEIVER STREET 1</fo:inline><fo:block /><fo:inline
            keep-with-previous.within-line="always"
            inline-progression-dimension.minimum="12pt"
            inline-progression-dimension.optimum="100%" border-bottom="thin solid black"
            ><axf:tab />RECEIVER STREET 2, RECEIVER STREET 3</fo:inline></fo:block>
</fo:flow>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:text>Title:</xsl:text>
<fo:inline keep-with-previous.within-line="always" white-space="normal" border-bottom="thin solid black">
<xsl:value-of select="/Report/value"/>
<fo:leader leader-length.optimum="100%"/>
</fo:inline>
```

This is a row with the title and value underlined to the right edge. If the value wraps, the next line will be similarly underlined.